# Excel formula needed: counts days elapsed over varied row lengths and N/A cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to create a formula that will tell me the number of weekdays that has elapsed between the date entered into column M and the last date to be entered into columns N-Q for each row. Ideally I would also like the formula to be able to handle the N/As in N7:O8 and skip to the last date entered in columns P-Q of that row.

[image: [Screengrab of my current data set up]

Apologies if this is a really obvious question, I'm still trying to get the basics of excel.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH to return the last cell with a date:

```
INDEX($M2:$Q2,MATCH(1E+99,$M2:$Q2))
```

Then we use NETWORKDAYS

```
=NETWORKDAYS($M2,INDEX($M2:$Q2,MATCH(1E+99,$M2:$Q2)))
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much for the help!